# Spring Security rejecting request because of a ; in URL headers

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

Can anyone advise how to configure Spring Boot to either ignore ';' in request headers or better still deal with them without crashing out?
I am calling a HTTPS endpoint and my browser is passing the header user-agent as below:

```
-H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36' \
```

When I check my logs I see this message:

```
Apr 22 00:10:44 ip-10-0-1-25 web: 2021-04-22 00:10:44.556  WARN 5560 --- [nio-5000-exec-8] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]
Apr 22 01:35:10 ip-10-0-1-25 web: 2021-04-22 01:35:10.672  INFO 5560 --- [nio-5000-exec-6] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header
Apr 22 01:35:10 ip-10-0-1-25 web: Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
Apr 22 01:35:10 ip-10-0-1-25 web: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
Apr 22 01:35:10 ip-10-0-1-25 web: at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:467) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
Apr 22 01:35:10 ip-10-0-1-25 web: at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:294) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
Apr 22 01:35:10 ip-10-0-1-25 web: at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
Apr 22 01:35:10 ip-10-0-1-25 web: at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
Apr 22 01:35:10 ip-10-0-1-25 web: at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
Apr 22 01:35:10 ip-10-0-1-25 web: at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
Apr 22 01:35:10 ip-10-0-1-25 web: at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
Apr 22 01:35:10 ip-10-0-1-25 web: at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
Apr 22 01:35:10 ip-10-0-1-25 web: at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
Apr 22 01:35:10 ip-10-0-1-25 web: at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
Apr 22 01:35:11 ip-10-0-1-25 web: 2021-04-22 01:35:11.999  INFO 5560 --- [nio-5000-exec-4] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header
Apr 22 01:35:12 ip-10-0-1-25 web: Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
Apr 22 01:35:12 ip-10-0-1-25 web: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
Apr 22 01:35:12 ip-10-0-1-25 web: at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:467) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
Apr 22 01:35:12 ip-10-0-1-25 web: at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:294) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
Apr 22 01:35:12 ip-10-0-1-25 web: at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
Apr 22 01:35:12 ip-10-0-1-25 web: at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
Apr 22 01:35:12 ip-10-0-1-25 web: at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
Apr 22 01:35:12 ip-10-0-1-25 web: at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
Apr 22 01:35:12 ip-10-0-1-25 web: at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
Apr 22 01:35:12 ip-10-0-1-25 web: at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
Apr 22 01:35:12 ip-10-0-1-25 web: at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
Apr 22 01:35:12 ip-10-0-1-25 web: at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Tomcat doesn't complain about the headers, but the request line `GET <path> HTTP/1.1`.  What URL did you try to retrieve? Probably it wasn't properly URL encoded.

Comment: Hey, the URL is a private one but it has no ; in it, when I modify the headers and drop out user-agent it works:
    https://api.**********.com/api/authenticate' \
    >   -H 'Accept: application/json' \
    >   -H 'Referer: https://

Comment: The line number in the stack trace (cf. [source code](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/54502a9e8796f87ff77b1e32251e2836f6671149/java/org/apache/coyote/http11/Http11InputBuffer.java#L467)) indicates that you have an invalid character in the query part, e.g. `http://api.example.com/api/authenticate?>>`. What are you using as HTTP client? Maybe your client concatenates the header to the URI?

Comment: When I copy the Curl request and run it in a terminal it works fine, no issues, no exceptions in logs on the spring server.  But when I make the call in Chrome that issue, so you might be right about it concatenating the entire request, I am not sure however how to make the server accept it but its another avenue to investigate so thanks :-)